# Word/term for users who are not experts and scientists

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, meaning-in-context

In the field of computer science, what should users who are  not experts and scientists be called? 
I've come up with **ordinary users** or **regular users**. Any formal alternative or widely-accepted term/word?

Answer (score 4):

People who are not scientists are laymen.

> [**Layman**](https://www.google.gr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=laymen%20definition): a person without professional or specialized knowledge in a particular subject.

Layman: a person without professional or specialized knowledge in a particular subject.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/layman

Comment: Please check for possible duplicates, especially where they are likely to exist, before giving an answer.

Comment: How do you check for possible duplicates?

Comment: Good point. Obviously, opting for a search for 'A person who isn't skilled in a particular field' here would be a sign of super-powers. I thought that there was a fair chance that this had been covered before, and, to be honest, 'layman' rang a bell. A search for 'layman' turned up the previous question as the 13th hit.

Comment: What's obvious to one person sounds like Greek to another. I still haven't understood how to do a search. I'm not computer savvy. I understand that a search would be useful, but that's not something I know how to do yet, and would appreciate having it explained to me. I would also point out that even if a question had been answered before. I might answer it in a completely different way, after reading how it was previously explained of course, once I've understood how to do a search, not something in my set of skills yet, like playing Chopin on the piano and playing poker.

Comment: But ELU policy is that you close-vote a duplicate rather than give an answer there.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Can you explain to me how to check for possible duplicates?

Comment: I would appreciate someone explaining to me how to check for duplicates, thank you.

Comment: The top bar on the ELU screen has a 'Search Q&A' window. I typed 'layman' there, pressed 'enter' on my keyboard, and looked through the hits that came up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37988/discussion-between-cathy-gartaganis-and-edwin-ashworth).